# What is the meaning of <%: %>

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does “ <%: ” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662346/what-does-do)

What is the meaning of <%: %> tags that you can use with ASP .NET 4.5? In particular, the colon after the %.

Thanks.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676236/are-and-the-same-thing-as-embbed-code-expression-blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the equivalent to `<%= %>` but automatically HTML encodes the content before it renders.