# What is the meaning of <%- %> tags in html?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

Okay I've been searching for this one and found a possible duplicate here ([what does " <%: " do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662346/what-does-do)). However this question adresses <%= and <%:, but not <%-.

So just to be sure I'm still asking my question.

I'm trying to setup a node.js/express/d3 application rendered on the server side. I found a repo describing what I want to do here:
https://github.com/gregjopa/d3-server-side-demo/blob/master/index.html

In that html code there is a snippet that I'd like to actually convert in jade:

```
    <h1>D3 Server-side Demo</h1>

<%-
  barChartHelper.getBarChart({
    data: fixtureData,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    xAxisLabel: '2012',
    yAxisLabel: 'Views',
    containerId: 'bar-chart-small'
  })
%>
```

So I have two questions:
1)What is the meaning of the <%- %> in html? 
And
2) How do I write this in jade?
Thanks,

Comment: i'm not sure i've ever seen those in a valid html document before.

Comment: Your title says `<-%` but your code shows `<%-`. Which one did you meet?

Comment: It has no meaning in HTML. You need to identify what template language you are using. In EJS (which uses similar syntax) it is an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The codebase you linked has [EmbeddedJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs) as a dependency. EJS is a templating library which allows for using those tags.

> Unescaped buffering with `<%- code %>`

So basically: These are not HTML tags, just tags belonging to a different templating language that allow inline JS code to be executed

You can use the same in Jade as explained in the [docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/)

> **Unescaped Buffered Code**
>
> Unescaped buffered code starts with `!=` and outputs the result of evaluating the JavaScript expression in the template.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!  That clarifies things. Indeed I didn't realized it was ejs. Cheers,